# how to append or add properties of object in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add properties  of object in string by comma separated.but I am not getting expected output here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/xbept0jn/2/ 
**Output**

```
business/codes/bank-abc,state-pqrbusiness/codes/bank-abc,state-pqrbusiness/codes/bank-abc,state-pqrbusiness/codes/bank-abc,state-pqr.cms
```

**Expected output**

```
business/codes/bank-abc,state-pqr.cms
```

code

```
var obj ={
 b:'abc',
 s:'pqr',
 d:'',
 br:''
} 
 function changeUrlUsingPushState() {
        var str = "business/codes/";
        str += obj.b  ? 'bank-' + obj.b : str;
        str += obj.s  ? ',state-' + obj.s : str;
        str += obj.d  ? ',district-' + obj.d : str;
        str += obj.br  ? ',branch-' + obj.br : str;
        str +='.cms';
        return str;

    }


    console.log(changeUrlUsingPushState())
```

Case II
if I take this obj

```
var obj ={
     b:'abc',
     s:'',
     d:'',
     br:'jjj'
    }
```

Output should be  `business/codes/bank-abc,branch-jjj.cms`

Comment: You probably want `str += obj.s  ? ',state-' + obj.s : ''`, not `: str`

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the string every time instead of appending nothing when the value is falsy. `str += obj.b ? 'bank-' + obj.b : str` can be changed to `str += obj.b ? 'bank-' + obj.b : ''` and it will work:

```js
var obj = {
  b: 'abc',
  s: 'pqr',
  d: '',
  br: ''
}

function changeUrlUsingPushState() {
  var str = "business/codes/";
  str += obj.b ? 'bank-' + obj.b : '';
  str += obj.s ? ',state-' + obj.s : '';
  str += obj.d ? ',district-' + obj.d : '';
  str += obj.br ? ',branch-' + obj.br : '';
  str += '.cms';
  return str;

}


console.log(changeUrlUsingPushState())
```